# Unexpected behaviour in list value change

Tags: python

I defined this function:

```
def newMap(dim, n):

    tc = [0 for i in range(n)]

    return [[tc for _ in range(dim)] for _ in range(dim)]
```

Which creates a list of lists of zeroes. For example

```
m = newMap(2,2)
print(m)
```

returns

```
[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

I want to change one os the zeroes to obtain `[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]` and tried doing so by

```
m[0][0][0] = 1
```

which, unexpectedly returns `[[[1, 0], [1, 0]], [[1, 0], [1, 0]]]`  instead of `[[[1, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]`.

However, if I defined `a = [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]`, and then do

```
a[0][0][0] = 1
print(a)
```

it returns `[[[1, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]`, which is what I want.

Why does this happen? Shouldn't the two definitions be equivalent? How can I prevent it from happening in the first case?

Comment: How is your a different than m? They look the same.

Comment: Objects. Shallow copies all around. This *is* the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use tc.copy() this should fix it, i tried it and it works:

```
def newMap(dim, n):

    tc = [0 for i in range(n)]

    return [[tc.copy() for _ in range(dim)] for _ in range(dim)]


a = newMap(2,2)  

a 
#[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]

a[0][0][0] = 1
#[[[1, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```